# Check if file is a symlink in Freepascal

Tags: linux, pascal, freepascal

I'm reading various files and directories with the FindFirst / FindNext functions as described [here](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/findfirst.html).

The only problem I have, is that I can't figure out if the file is a symlink. In the file attributes there is no constant or flag and I can't find a function for testing for symlinks.

Comment: What OS? If it's Windows, do you mean a Windows 7 symlink, or a junction reparse point?

Comment: I'm developing under Linux.

Comment: This afaik has been abstracted since Kylix. (fasymlink), so OS shouldn't matter, unless you use an older FPC or Delphi that doesn't grok Windows symlinks. I haven't tested Windows symlinks with FPC yet though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original idea of using findfirst is best, since it is a portable solution (windows has symlinks too nowadays). The only thing to adapt is to request symlink checking in the attributes you pass to findfirst:

```
uses sysutils;

var info : TSearchrec;

begin
  // the or fasymlink in the next file is necessary so that findfirst
  //     uses (fp)lstat instead of (fp)stat
  If FindFirst ('../*',faAnyFile or fasymlink ,Info)=0 then
     begin
    Repeat
      With Info do
        begin
        If (Attr and fasymlink) = fasymlink then
           Writeln('found symlink: ', info.name)
        else
           writeln('not a symlink: ', info.name,' ',attr);
        end;
    Until FindNext(info)<>0;
    end;
  FindClose(Info);
end.
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use fpstat from BaseUnix:

Something like this

```
uses baseUnix;
var s: stat;
fpstat(filname, s);
if s.st_mode = S_IFLNK then
  writeln('is link');
```

that also gives you a lot of other information about the file  (times, size...)

Comment: You need lstat. But this makes it OS specific for no good reason

Answer (score 1):

The function fpLStat is the answer:

```
var
  fileStat: stat;

begin 
  if fpLStat('path/to/file', fileStat) = 0 then
  begin
    if fpS_ISLNK(fileStat.st_mode) then
      Writeln ('File is a link');
    if fpS_ISREG(fileStat.st_mode) then
      Writeln ('File is a regular file');
    if fpS_ISDIR(fileStat.st_mode) then
      Writeln ('File is a directory');
    if fpS_ISCHR(fileStat.st_mode) then
      Writeln ('File is a character device file');
    if fpS_ISBLK(fileStat.st_mode) then
      Writeln ('File is a block device file');
    if fpS_ISFIFO(fileStat.st_mode) then
      Writeln ('File is a named pipe (FIFO)');
    if fpS_ISSOCK(fileStat.st_mode) then
      Writeln ('File is a socket');
  end;
end.
```

Prints out:

```
test_symlink
File is a link
test
File is a directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint using fpstat. But it does not seem to work. 
I have two files, a directory and a symlink to a directory:

```
drwxrwxr-x   2 marc marc   4096 Okt  1 09:40 test
lrwxrwxrwx   1 marc marc     11 Dez  5 13:49 test_symlink -> /home/marc/
```

If I use fpstat on these to files I get:

```
Result of fstat on file test
Inode   : 23855105
Mode    : 16877
nlink   : 92
uid     : 1000
gid     : 1000
rdev    : 0
Size    : 12288
Blksize : 4096
Blocks  : 24
atime   : 1354711751
mtime   : 1354711747
ctime   : 1354711747

Result of fstat on file test_symlink
Inode   : 23855105
Mode    : 16877
nlink   : 92
uid     : 1000
gid     : 1000
rdev    : 0
Size    : 12288
Blksize : 4096
Blocks  : 24
atime   : 1354711751
mtime   : 1354711747
ctime   : 1354711747
```

No difference in Attribute st_mode. I think that fpstat gets the stats of the link destination, which indeed is a directory...